# How does string literal concatenation work in Java?

Tags: java, string

If we are concatenating two string literals in Java, then how and where does the new String get created?

```
class StringClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String a = "java";
        String b = "ja";
        String c = "va";
        String d = b + c;

        System.out.println(a == d);
    }

}
```

If both `a` and `d` are part of the string pool, then why `a == d` return `false`?

Is `d` not a part of the string pool?

Comment: My guess is that while `a` and `d` are _equal_ per the definition of `String#equals`, the variable `d` is not pointing to the string pool.

Comment: Since `b + d` is not a *constant expression* it is evaluated at runtime.  A string pool entry is not created there.

Comment: BTW title is misleading, there is no "literal concatenation" in posted code. How it would work: the compiler does the concatenation, and compiles it as a single literal (e.g. `"ja" + "va"` would be the same as having coded `"java"` directly)

Comment: Why do you care? This knowledge is esoteric and not needed to be able to program in Java. You only need this knowledge if you're answering useless trivia questions, or if you are deep into doing hard and deep optimization of a Java program.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [Runtime String concatenation evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883730/runtime-string-concatenation-evaluation)

Comment: Try it again with `a`, `b`, and `c` as `final`.

Comment: People do seem to get hung up on 'where the bits are stored' (heap? stack? literal pool?), none of which is necessary to understand the meaning of a java program.  Linguistic issues such as 'scope' are much more important.

Comment: Not only is this knowledge esoteric as [noted by Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77421224/how-does-string-literal-concatenation-work-in-java#comment136489452_77421224), it might possibly change in future versions of Java.

Comment: fortunately curiosity is one of the characteristics of us humans...

Answer (score 9):

Since `b + c` is not a *constant expression* it is evaluated at runtime.  A string pool entry is not created there.

> "Is `d` not a part of string pool?"

CORRECT.  The value of `d` has not been added to the string pool.  Only strings resulting from a *constant expression* are added to the string pool *automatically*.

A *constant expression* is defined in [JLS 15.29](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29).  I will not reproduce it here in its entirety, but I encourage you to **take the time to read it**.  Intuitively, a *constant expression* is one that can be evaluated at compile time, but it is a bit more complicated than that.

The reason that `b + c` is NOT a constant expression (here) is that `b` and `c` were not declared as `final`.

---

Having said all of the above, there is really no need to understand the details of the string pool and when something will be added to it.  All you really need to do is follow this "rule":

> Do not use `==` to test if `String` values are equal.  Use the `String.equals(Object)` method.  Always.

Also, do not use `String.intern()` directly.  In recent versions of Java, GC's are able to automatically de-dup any long-lived `String` objects<sup>*</sup>.  If you are using `intern()` so that you can use `==`,

1. it is a micro-optimization that could well not be worth it (since interning and the string pool itself incur runtime overheads), and
2. it is risky ... since you have to be sure that you intern *all* of the `String` objects you are going to test ... to avoid incorrect results, and
3. it makes your code more complicated and harder to reason about.

---

<sup>* Actually, the GC only dedups the strings' respective internal backing arrays.  The affected strings are still distinct, so `==` still doesn't work.  The deduping (currently) just saves space ... modulo some 2nd order performance issues.</sup>

Comment: @user85421 this is necessarily so: `.intern()` needs to find an already interned string this is equal to the new string and for this it needs to call `equals()` between the current string and an interned string at least once (and most probably also calls `hashCode()` on the current string if the intern table is built similar to a hashmap)

Comment: @user85421 I had the impression that you wanted a confirmation that `a == b.intern()` is slower than `a.equals(b)` and I can say with confidence that this is necessarily so.

Answer (score 5):

> If we are concatenating two String literals in Java

That's not what your code is doing though. It's concatenating two *non-constant variables*:

```java
String b = "ja";
String c = "va";
String d = b + c;
```

If I understand correctly, the compiler "sees" that concatenation, and notes that the operands aren't constant - so it leaves the concatenation to execution time.

If you change those variables to be *constant variables* by using the `final` modifier, the compiler notes that both operands of the string concatenation are constant expressions, and then your code prints `true`:

```java
String a = "java";

// These are now constant variables
final String b = "ja";
final String c = "va";

// Concatenation of constant expressions
String d = b + c;

// This now prints true
System.out.println(a == d);
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... If both `a` and `d` are part of the string pool, then why `a == d` return `false`? ..."*

A great question.

Firstly, if you use the *[String#intern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#intern())* method, it will return *true*.

```java
String d = (b + c).intern();
```

The *JavaDoc* for *intern* states the following.

> *... All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned. String literals are defined in section [3.10.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) of the The Java Language Specification. ...*

And, section *15.29* defines, *"Constant Expressions"*.

> *A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following: ...*
>
> - *The additive operators + and - ([§15.18](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18))*
> - *Simple names ([§6.5.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.1)) that refer to constant variables ([§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)).*
>
> ...

So, you'll need to define *b* and *c* as, *"constant variables"*.

*[4.12.4. final Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)*.

> *A constant variable is a final variable of primitive type or type String that is initialized with a constant expression ([§15.29](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29)). Whether a variable is a constant variable or not may have implications with respect to class initialization ([§12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1)), binary compatibility ([§13.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1)), reachability ([§14.22](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.22)), and definite assignment ([§16.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.1.1)).*

Thus, making *b* and *c* both *final*, will cause the values to be *"interned"*.

```java
String a = "java";
final String b = "ja";
final String c = "va";
String d = b + c;
System.out.println(a == d);
```

Output

```
true
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason why a == d returns false has to do with how the + operator and the String concatenation works in Java.

When you are concatenating two String objects  b and c using the + operator, Java creates a new String object to hold the concatenated result. Even though the value of d is same as a, the resulting String object d is a different object in memory.This is because Java creates a new String object for the result of the concatenation, and it doesn't reuse the original String objects.

When you use == to compare them, it checks for reference equality, and since a and d refer to different objects, the comparison returns false.

If you want to compare the contents of a and d, you should use the **.equals() method**, which checks for string equality based on their content:

```
System.out.println(a.equals(d));
```

Comment: @user85421 Actually You are right. I corrected my answer.